# Problema con Checkbuttons en Python

Tags: python

De más está decir que soy nuevo en esto, se darán cuenta por sí solos. Últimamente estuve viendo lo básico de interfaces gráficas y me surgió un problema con los checkbuttons. El programa es simple, se supone que debe almacenar un valor al ser presionado, el cual pasará por la función y arrojará texto indicando la opción seleccionada:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

foto=PhotoImage(file="imagen.png")

labelimagen=Label(raiz, image=foto)
labelimagen.pack()

frame=Frame(raiz)
frame.pack()

labeltexto_1=Label(frame, text="Seleccione la/s ocupación/es:")
labeltexto_1.pack()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

al_tboton=StringVar()
al_eboton=StringVar()

def funcion_botones():
    textoalmacen=""

    if al_tboton.get()==1:
        textoalmacen+=" Trabajador"
    if al_eboton.get()==1:
        textoalmacen+=" Estudiante"

    textofinal.config(text=textoalmacen)

tboton=Checkbutton(frame, text="Trabajador", variable=al_tboton, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=funcion_botones)
tboton.pack()

eboton=Checkbutton(frame, text="Estudiante", variable=al_eboton, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=funcion_botones)
eboton.pack()

labeltexto_2=Label(frame, text="Has seleccionado:")
labeltexto_2.pack()

textofinal=Label(frame)
textofinal.pack()


raiz.mainloop()
```

El problema está en dos aspectos específicos y cruciales. En primer lugar, no sé por qué, pero los botones me aparecen ya seleccionados. El segundo problema, la función parece no funcionar y no se muestra el texto debido debajo del todo.

Desde ya muchísimas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el momento que se crea un `checkbutton` este inicia con un estado indeterminado, por esa razon se crea una variable para contener su valor. En tu caso:

`al_tboton` y `al_eboton`... en lugar de hacerlos `StringVar` hacelos `BooleanVar`, para determinar si el `checkbutton` esta seleccionado o no. El valor por defecto al iniciar es `False` por lo que ninguno esta seleccionado esto lo puedes modificar con un .`get`.

Creo que eso es todo.

Tu código funcional debería ir algo así:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

#foto=PhotoImage(file="imagen.png")

labelimagen=Label(raiz, text="Imagen")
labelimagen.pack()

frame=Frame(raiz)
frame.pack()

labeltexto_1=Label(frame, text="Seleccione la/s ocupación/es:")
labeltexto_1.pack()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

al_tboton=BooleanVar()
al_eboton=BooleanVar()

def funcion_botones():
    textoalmacen=""

    if al_tboton.get()==True:
        textoalmacen+=" Trabajador"
    elif al_eboton.get()==True:
        textoalmacen+=" Estudiante"

    textofinal.config(text=textoalmacen)

tboton=Checkbutton(frame, text="Trabajador", variable=al_tboton, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=funcion_botones)
tboton.pack()

eboton=Checkbutton(frame, text="Estudiante", variable=al_eboton, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=funcion_botones)
eboton.pack()

labeltexto_2=Label(frame, text="Has seleccionado:")
labeltexto_2.pack()

textofinal=Label(frame)
textofinal.pack()


raiz.mainloop()
```

Comente la imagen por que no la tenia y no me quise complicar la vida, creo que no habrá problema con eso...

Otra cosa, por conveniencia se recomienda no importar `tkinter` con el asterisco `*` si no `as tk` y aplicar este alias a todos los widgets.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

P.D. anexo unos links que me fueron de ayuda [este de aqui](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/checkbox-checkbutton-en-tcltk-tkinter/) y [este de aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm) y tambien [este](https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/interfaces-graficas-con-tkinter/widget-checkbutton-seleccionable/).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Siempre dudé del uso de StringVar(), pero en los videos el profesor utilizaba estos y siempre parecía funcionar. Con eso, ahora, me surge otra duda. ¿Cómo pudo haber hecho él para que le funcionase así? (Su código es muy similar al que ves arriba, utilizando StringVar(); pero también cabe aclarar que la clase es del 2017, quizá algo cambió en Python).